# Stop the output process

Tags: java

```
//Calculate the amount of money you will receive based on your option

if (n == 0) {

    while (death - 1 >= counter) {

        System.out.format("Week %2d Linear: $%.2f Exponential: $%.2f\n", counter, a, p);

        if ((death - 1 == counter) && (a >= p)) {

            System.out.format("Your uncle dies in week %2d. But you were lucky and received an extra " +
                    "$%.2f dollars.\n", death, ((death * initial) - ((Math.pow(2, (death - 1)) / 100))));
        }
        if ((p > a) && (death - 1 >= counter)) {
            System.out.format("Your uncle dies in week %2d. But you were unlucky and missed an extra " +
                    "$%.2f dollars.\n", death, (p - a));
        }
        a += initial;
        counter++;
        p = p * 2;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Week  1 Linear: $1.39 Exponential: $0.01
>
> Week  2 Linear: $2.79 Exponential: $0.02
>
> Week  3 Linear: $4.18 Exponential: $0.04
>
> Week  4 Linear: $5.58 Exponential: $0.08
>
> Week  5 Linear: $6.97 Exponential: $0.16
>
> Week  6 Linear: $8.36 Exponential: $0.32
>
> Week  7 Linear: $9.76 Exponential: $0.64
>
> Week  8 Linear: $11.15 Exponential: $1.28
>
> Week  9 Linear: $12.55 Exponential: $2.56
>
> Week 10 Linear: $13.94 Exponential: $5.12
>
> Week 11 Linear: $15.34 Exponential: $10.24
>
> Week 12 Linear: $16.73 Exponential: $20.48
>
> Your uncle dies in week 31. But you were unlucky and missed an extra
>   $3.75 dollars.
>
> Week 13 Linear: $18.12 Exponential: $40.96
>
> Your uncle dies in week 31. But you were unlucky and missed an extra
>   $22.84 dollars.
>
> Week 14 Linear: $19.52 Exponential: $81.92
>
> Your uncle dies in week 31. But you were unlucky and missed an extra
>   $62.40 dollars.

My question is how can i stop my if statement so that when p>a it will stop outputting and say he has died. Week 12 in my example i want it to stop outputting and say he died.

Comment: its almost if at twelve when p is finally greater than a i want to put a break but i can't really put an inequality saying when p finally passes a stop outputting

Comment: You should really fix your indentation.

Comment: sorry i just started using java and this site..

Comment: What's death? It's not initialised in the code you posted.

Comment: death is a random generated variable from 0-40 a is a random value from 0-5000 and p is penny and the value is double with each week and the counter is simply a counter for each week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the (death-1 >= counter) condition gets validated in the while condition, its redundant for the second if statement. Also, the two If statements are mutually exclusive so you can use and if .. else conditional, that way a statement is validated only once and is relatively faster / readable.

```
                if ((death - 1 == counter) && (a >= p)) {
                    System.out.format("Your uncle dies in week %2d. But you were lucky and received an extra " +
                            "$%.2f dollars.\n", death, ((death * initial) - ((Math.pow(2, (death - 1)) / 100))));
                }else if(p > a) {
                    System.out.format("Your uncle dies in week %2d. But you were unlucky and missed an extra " +
                            "$%.2f dollars.\n", death, (p - a));
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a ton of information to go with here; but generally, if you want to stop looping when a condition is met, you can either `break` the loop or change a boolean variable which is checked in the while loop, preventing it from looping again.

Comment: i understand but in the output when it hits week 12 (p > a) so it begins to output that he dies. On week 12 thats the only time i want it to output because its the first time (p > a) is there a way to stop the output after that? would i just add a break after it?

Comment: Do you want to stop *all* output, effectively ending the program? Or only the output saying that the uncle has died?

If you want all output to stop, the break will take you out of the while loop and the program will end.

Comment: at 12 it will output he died because I only want to output when p finally surpasses a. but at 13 I don't want it to output anything

Comment: Then you want to break after the output.